# Returns the number of characters in a Word

Tags: java

```
private static StringBuffer sb;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Text in a string
    String text = "This is a poor sentence in grammar.";

    String[] words = text.split("[ .!?]");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        if (words[i].length() >= 1) {
            for (int k = 0; k < words[i].length(); k++) {
                if (Character.isLetter(words[i].charAt(k)))
                    counter++;
            }
            sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append(counter).append(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Can we optimize this code more?
 My Ouptut is:-

```
4 2 1 4 8 2 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to optimize more.  Instead of splitting the string only at punctuations you need to split it at anything that isn't a letter.  Then you can just use the length function to find the length of the words.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String text = "This is a poor   sentence in grammar.";

String[] words = text.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    if(words[i].length()>0)
        System.out.print(words[i].length()+" ");
}
```

Comment: Nice and short.  Adding a '+' would also eat up things like multiple spaces or ", " separating words.  E.g. "[^a-zA-Z]+".

Comment: Yes, this is true.  I will edit the post to reflect this, nice addition @phatfingers

Answer (score 3):

You keep creating a new `StringBuffer` instead of using the original one.

Move the `StringBuffer` declaration into the `main` method (no reason to have it outside of it), create a single `StringBuffer` at the declaration. Remove the `new StringBuffer()` towards the end so you're always using the same one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String text = "This is a poor   sentence in grammar.";

    String[] words = text.split("[ .!?]");
    for (String word : words) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(word.charAt(i))) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter > 0) {
            sb.append(counter).append(" ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

I'd also optimize for readability as well, and refactor the letter-counting code into its own method, turning the mainline code into this:

```
String[] words = text.split("[ .!?]");
for (String word : words) {
    int counter = countLetters(word);
    if (counter > 0) {
        sb.append(counter).append(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks for the comment after posting this question I have solved that StringBuffer issue. And is there any way to optimize this code more?

Comment: Regarding further ways to optimize the code:  If on Java 1.5 or above, use a StringBuilder instead of a StringBuffer - as there is no possibility for multi-thread access and no need for StringBuffer's synchronization.  If really serious about this, assuming the routine would be called multiple times, pre-compile the "[ .!?]" into a Pattern (reusable Regular Expression).

Comment: Pre-compiling the regex doesn't help if the regex is only used once.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to optimize based on how fast your code executes (which may not equate to being optimized in terms of maintenance costs or lines of code), then your best bet is to not use a regular expression for this simple a task.  The code below, for example, will run tens or even hundreds of times faster than the good clean example @Boundless presented.  In the long run, I'd rather maintain his example, but it's worth noting if you ever had any real reason to optimize some very highly used piece of code.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
char text[] = "This is a poor   sentence in grammar.".toCharArray();
int word=0;
for (int i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
    char c=text[i];
    if (c>='A' && c<='z' && (c<='Z' || c>='a')) {
        word++;
    } else if (word>0) {
        sb.append(word);
        sb.append(' ');
        word=0;
    }
}
// Chop off trailing space
sb.setLength(Math.max(0, sb.length()-1));
```

Comment: The odd arrangement of char comparisons is an attempt to fail fast on punctuation, which usually falls earlier than 'A' on an ASCII chart.